# How to let a template function accept anything you can construct some basic_string_view out

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, string-view

I'm trying to write a simple template function which accepts all possible basic_string_view but i always get the compiler error "no matching overloaded function found".

I don't know the reason; explicitly converting to string_view by the caller works but i'd like to avoid that; or is intentionally made hard?

Are there deduction guidelines which prevent this?

And is there a easy way to implement this as a template?

Here (and on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kse8bKbE6)) is what i tried:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

template <typename CharT, typename Traits> void func(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> value)
//template <typename CharT> void func(std::basic_string_view<CharT> value)
//void func(std::string_view value)
{}

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::string_view sv(s);
    char const cs[] = "";
    std::string_view csv(cs);

    std::wstring ws;
    std::wstring_view wsv(ws);
    wchar_t const wcs[] = L"";
    std::wstring_view wcsv(wcs);

    func(s);
    func(sv);
    func(cs);
    func(csv);

    func(ws);
    func(wsv);
    func(wcs);
    func(wcsv);
}
```

Here are the errors msvc, clang and gcc show:

```
error C2672: 'func': no matching overloaded function foundx64 msvc v19.latest #3
error C2783: 'void func(T)': could not deduce template argument for '<unnamed-symbol>'x64 msvc v19.latest #3
error: no matching function for call to 'func'x86-64 clang (trunk) #1
error: no matching function for call to 'func(std::string&)'x86-64 gcc (trunk) #2
```

**EDIT:**

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j5d678TvM) of a blend of Yakks c++20 answer with the addition of Jonathans raw character pointer support.

Comment: please include the error message in the question. Btw gcc (and perhaps also clangs) error message seems to be a bit more informative: https://godbolt.org/z/c8vqqcaMv

Comment: The compiler has to deduce CharT and Traits for your basic_string_view... But it can only do this if the function actually gets passed a basic_string_view. If you pass it something else, deduction fails, because whatever you passed it doesn't have CharT and Traits. Conversions only apply when a suitable function exists; at the deduction step, there is no function yet, so no conversion will take place.

Comment: To be clear, your function template here already does "only accept basic_string_view." It's just that you want to accept _more_ than just that - you want to accept anything you can construct some basic_string_view out of. The wording of the question doesn't make that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's also possible to do this using just C++20 by checking whether the argument passed to the function is a range. The range can then be converted to a `basic_string_view` using its constructor overload that takes iterators.

I've also added an overload that can deal with char pointers since those aren't ranges.

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <ranges>


template <typename CharT, typename Traits>
void func(std::basic_string_view<CharT, Traits> value) {
    // ...
}

template<typename S> requires std::ranges::contiguous_range<S>
void func(const S& s) {
    func(std::basic_string_view{std::ranges::begin(s), std::ranges::end(s)});
}

template<typename S> requires (!std::ranges::range<S> && requires (S s) { std::basic_string_view<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s[0])>>(s); })
void func(const S& s) {
    func(std::basic_string_view<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(s[0])>>(s));
}
```

Comment: I think don't get the part about the char* overload; for me it also compiles [without it](https://godbolt.org/z/jbosEdfEz). And [with it](https://godbolt.org/z/WrE1v1ahn), it also compiles for `func(new int)`.

Comment: ```func(&cs[0]);``` won't compile without it, since that's an actual ```const char *```. ```func(cs)``` is passing a ```const char[n]``` to the function, which is not a pointer (but a valid range so it uses the range overload). ```func(new int);``` should in fact compile since ```std::basic_string_view<int>``` is a valid thing.

Comment: It also compiles with [`func(new double)`](https://godbolt.org/z/x5MEMxr6n)

Comment: @ridilculous So does ```std::basic_string_view<double> ohno = new double;```. This is valid.

Comment: Oo, sry! Guess it's really time for me to dig deep in basic_string_view.

Comment: The range overload may be broken with the non-sized range.

Comment: @康桓瑋 I'm not quite sure in what way it'd be broken, could you elaborate? Any contiguous range must provide begin and end after all; whether they operate in constant time should not be relevant here as far as I know.

Comment: @JonathanS. `contiguous_range` is not necessarily `sized_range`, `basic_string_view(It first, End last)` requires `End` must satisfy `sized_sentinel_for` for `It` so that the size of string can be obtained in constant time. https://godbolt.org/z/fMznz45a4

Comment: Interesting. It looks like the problem lies in basic_string_view itself and not in the "func" overload though, since basic_string_view appears to expect a sized range for both the range constructor and the iterator constructor (it expects to be able to get the distance between begin and end). So it's impossible in general to construct a basic_string_view from a non-sized range, as far as I can tell. I don't think it matters much whether the template substitution fails in the requires clause or in the body of the function itself.

Comment: "*I don't think it's a defect if the range overload fails in that case since there's no way for it to work anyway.*" It's *just* because your overload doesn't constrain `sized_range<S>`, the constraints of this overload *should* be consistent with `basic_string_view(It first, End last)`.

Comment: The `s[0]` overload looks quite dangerous.  For example, a `deque` has a `[0]` but cannot be converted to a basic string view.

Comment: My reasoning is this: The range overload is not going to work for non-sized ranges, so it won't get selected for overload resolution anyway due to SFINAE. You're right that you could require ```sized_range<S>``` too, though. That wouldn't hurt but it also won't change anything. And about the ```s[0]``` overload: That ```s[0]``` is just there to get the type for CharT; ```s[0]``` isn't actually evaluated. The argument just gets passed as-is to the ```basic_string_view(const CharT *)``` constructor. If that won't work, the template will get SFINAE'd away.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont To address your edit as well: ```deque``` is also a range so the requires clause of that overload is not met, it'll go to the other one (with begin and end) instead. It only applies to "stuff that can be indexed but is not a range" - so, char pointers, or things that can be converted to char pointers.

Comment: "*The argument just gets passed as-is to the basic_string_view(const CharT *) constructor.*" So why not just constrain the type must be a pointer? Your constrains clause is too verbose IMO.

Comment: @康桓瑋 For types that provide an ```operator const CharT *``` and a ```const CharT& operator[]```. You can construct a ```basic_string_view``` from those too (via the pointer constructor overload and an implicit conversion) but requiring actual pointers would disallow this valid usage.

Comment: "*For types that provide an operator const CharT * and a const CharT& operator[].*" Ok, then for types that provide an `operator const CharT *` and delete `operator[]`?

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible to do that for such types in a generic way because there's no way to get at the type of CharT without already knowing it beforehand. ```operator[]``` is needed to get CharT because it can be named without already knowing CharT.

Answer (score 6):

`basic_string_view` has a [range version of CTAD](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p1989r2.pdf) in C++23, so in C++23, you can use the `requires` clause to constrain `basic_string_view{s}` to be well-formed, and deduce its type by borrowing the CTAD of `basic_string_view` in the function body

```
#include <string_view>

template<typename StrLike>
  requires requires (const StrLike& s) 
  { std::basic_string_view{s}; }
void func(const StrLike& s) {
  auto sv = std::basic_string_view{s};
  // use sv
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5bY4hj7zo)

Comment: What does "CTAD" stand for? Does it just mean "constructor" (like the abbreviation "ctor"), or something else?

Comment: @Useless That's [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: I really like this; also that it easily expands to multiple parameters, f.e. https://godbolt.org/z/8dbP4fbWc

Answer (score 1):

It is in general impossible for the compiler to deduce the template arguments so a conversion can succeed. That is not how C++ templates were designed.

Given this:

```
char const cs[] = "";
func(cs);
```

The compiler would have to be able to answer

"What template arguments `CharT`, `Traits` must I deduce so there is an appropriate implicit conversion from `const char[1]` to `std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>`?"

Of course it cannot do that, at least not without somehow iterating over all types (which is infinite, countable set).

Unfortunately there are no deduction guides for template functions.

Answer (score 1):

@康桓瑋's answer is awesome.  But you should avoid unnamed concepts.  So:

```
#include <string_view>

template<typename ZLike, template<class...>class Z>
concept can_become = requires (const ZLike& s) {
  { Z{s} };
};

void func(const can_become<std::basic_string_view> auto& s) {
  auto sv = std::basic_string_view{s};
  // use sv
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/sn3vj3no6).

This can also be solved using [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) and earlier techniques:

```
template<class StrLike, std::enable_if_t<can_become_v<StrLike, std::basic_string_view>, bool> = true>
void func2(const StrLike& s) {
  auto sv = std::basic_string_view{s};
  // use sv
}
```

without concepts.

It isn't until [c++23](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b23) that `std::basic_string_view` had a CTAD that was SFINAE friendly.  Without it, you have to know the exact kind of `basic_string_view` your incoming type can convert to, and then use that specific type.  `operator basic_string_view<X,Y>()` can only be found if you have the specific type you want to cast to available.

You can work around this by creating the range based constructors of `basic_string_view`, and manually deducing the type of the character (and possibly traits) involved.

A pure [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) solution that doesn't support raw char pointers:

```
template<typename ZLike, template<class...>class Z>
concept can_range_become = requires (const ZLike& s) {
  { Z{std::ranges::begin(s), std::ranges::end(s)} };
};
template<typename T>
concept stringlike = can_range_become<T, std::basic_string_view> && std::ranges::contiguous_range<T>;

void func(const stringlike auto& s) {
  auto sv = std::basic_string_view{std::ranges::begin(s), std::ranges::end(s)};
  // use sv
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ExWxca1nM).

Comment: I tried to come up with a c++20 version based on your 1st example.

Comment: @ridilculous Well, you have to test for `continuous_range` in C++20 for the various `basic_string_view` ctors to be guaranteed valid.  So...

Comment: @ridilculous Written

Comment: `&& std::ranges::contiguous_range<T>` seems redundant here, the constructor already requires a `contiguous_iterator`.